# SQL update of grouped data using an aggregate

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a table by first grouping the data by column1, 
within each group of data I need to:
sort the data by column2,
populate Column4 with the top value from column3 (as sorted by column2)
Columns1,3,4 are varchar and Column 3 is an int.
I tried an update with a CTE and Top as:

```
Update a
Set a.col4 = c.Best
From Table1 a,
(Select Top (1) Col3 as Best, Col1, Col2
From Table1
Group By Col1
Order By Col2 DESC) c
where a.Col1 = c.Col1
```

but it seems to be selecting the top value from the table not from each group.  Does anyone know what is missing here or an easier way of doing this?
Starting Data:
    Col1       Col2    Col3        Col4
    unit101    11      unit118     NULL
    unit101    13      unit125     NULL
    unit101    12      unit135     NULL
    unit107    11      unit168     NULL
    unit107    10      unit199     NULL

Required result:
    Col1       Col2    Col3        Col4
    unit101    11      unit118     unit125
    unit101    13      unit125     unit125
    unit101    12      unit135     unit125
    unit107    11      unit168     unit168
    unit107    10      unit199     unit168

Column 4 needs to have the value from col3 where col 2 is at maximum value of the rows in the data as grouped by col1.

Comment: Can yo provide a [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)?  It is easier to answer questions like this if we can see samples of the input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'rank' to determine the 'best' and add that to your inner join. Below is a working exampole and provides the results you asked for

```
Update a
Set a.col4 = c.Best
From Table1 a
inner join
(
Select 
    Col3 as Best,
    Col1,
    BestRank=RANK()over(partition by Col1 order by Col2 desc )
From 
    Table1 b
) c on a.Col1 = c.Col1 and c.BestRank=1
```

Comment: Cool pattern @user1529235, now I'm curious I want to compare it against CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`

```
Update a
Set a.col4 = c.Best
From Table1 a
 CROSS APPLY (Select Top (1) Col3 as Best, Col1, Col2
              From Table1 t2
              where a.Col1 = t2.Col1
              Order By Col2 DESC) c
```

Comment: When I run this I get an error:  Table1.Col3 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.

Comment: I fixed the issue @user8091579, but for you to know the solution you picked is faster than this.